# Proving the Preposition: Log-Convexity of a Function and the Monotonicity of Ratios

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

While reading a research paper on log convexity, I encountered a preposition (which is my question). I tried to prove it. I'm not getting any idea how to proceed. The statement is as follows:

> Suppose $f: [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$ is continuous and has a constant sign. Then $f$ is log-convex (strictly log-convex) $ \iff x \mapsto \frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}$ is non-decreasing (increasing) on $[a, b-h]$ for each fixed $h > 0$.

Comment: Yesterday, I asked the same question with wrong interpretations that caused doubt and confusion for many. That is why I deleted it and posted it again.

Comment: As I said in response to your previous question: The following statements are equivalent for a *continuous* function $f: [a, b] \to \Bbb R^+$: 1) $f$ is log-convex. 2) $\log f$ is convex. 3) $\log f$ is Wright-convex, i.e. $ x \mapsto \log f(x+h)-\log f(x)$ is nondecreasing for every $h > 0$. 4) $x\mapsto f(x+h)/f(x)$ is nondecreasing for every $h>0$. – Please clarify which of these equivalences is unclear to you.

Comment: I have problem in , $log f$ wright convex $\iff$ $f(x+h)/f(x)$ is non decreasing.

Comment: $x\mapsto f(x+h)/f(x)$ is nondecreasing exactly if $x\mapsto \log(f(x+h)/f(x)) = \log f(x+h)-\log f(x)$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I have answered based on your comments. Could you please verify?

Comment: Looks good.....

Answer (score 2):

The answer was in front of eyes only. This answer is completely due to Martin's comments. I'm writing this answer as it requires the concept of Wright convex.

A function $f:[a,b] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is said to be Wright convex if, for every $\delta >0$ and $x \leq y$ with $x$ and $y+\delta \in  [a,b]$ we have $f(x+h) - f(x) \leq f(y+h) - f(y)$

$log f(x)$ is convex $\iff$ $log f(x)$ is Wright convex as $f$ is continuous (Due to Jensen).
i.e.,  for $ x \leq y,$ $\log f(x+h) - \log f(x) \leq \log f(y+h) - \log f(y) \iff \frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)} \leq \frac{f(y+h)}{f(y)}.$ The hypothesis constant sign says $\frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}$ is positive which allowed us writing $\log f(x+h) - \log f(x) = \log \frac{f(x+h)}{f(x)}.$

For the result of Jensen, see CONVEX FUNCTIONS AND THEIR APPLICATIONS A contemporary approach ( by Constantin P. Niculescu, Lars-Erik Persson) Theorem 1.1.4. or J. L. W. V. Jensen, Sur les fonctions convexes et les inegalités entreles valeurs moyennes, Acta Math., 30 (1906), 175-193.